# How is Thread.SpinWait useful on a single-core CPU?

Tags: .net, multithreading

On a single core machine, if a running thread spin-waits just because it is waiting for the release of a lock that another thread currently holds, then isn't the spin-wait a waste of CPU time because the thread that currently holds the lock is anyway on the wait queue?

Therefore, is spin waiting for the release of a lock valuable only on machines with multiple cores?

For that matter, this question applies to all the `Slim` objects such as `SemaphoreSlim` and `ReaderWriterLockSlim` as well.

Comment: I believe your assumptions are correct, but I don't have the facts to back up ***my*** assumptions so I am not going to post it as an answer.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, spin waiting is useless and counterproductive on single-core machines -- but such machines are increasingly rare.

.NET 4.0 introduces the more advanced [`SpinWait`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.threading.spinwait) structure. If used on a single-core machine it will immediately give up the current thread's time slice and allow progress to be made on other threads, since busy waiting for any length of time would do nothing but hold up the processor. (Spin waiting in this sense could still make sense for hardware drivers even on single core machines since the hardware can make progress in the background, but hardware drivers aren't written in IL, of course.)

Similarly, the `*Slim` types will not employ spinning if used on a single-core machine. They are still worthwhile to use when possible because, unlike their non-`Slim` counterparts, they are written to be faster, simpler and to require less resources (`Semaphore` is backed by a kernel object, for example, `SemaphoreSlim` is not).

In general, you should prefer the `*Slim` types regardless of the number of cores and use the `SpinWait` structure if you really need spinning (almost never, unless you're implementing your own synchronization primitive), since it will not actually spin unless it makes sense to do so.

Comment: SpinWait can also be useful when you are doing very very short (sub 15ms) waits for rate limiting a bit of looping code. (over 66 Hz you need SpinWaits between loops)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Thank you. What is rate limiting a loop and where can I read about it?

Comment: @JeroenMosterf Thank you very much.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 a peice of code that you want to run once every 10ms (for example reading from a sensor) would be a rate limited (because you are waiting for the 10ms to pass before you do it again) loop (because you are doing the action multiple times)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Thank you. How do you and from where do you read these things? I am fascinated but I don't even know what topic this is and where they are and what they are called and from where to read about them.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 nowhere really. It is stuff I learned in my computer science collage classes.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain But what is it called? Was it a part of Computer Systems Architecture? What was the class called?